# How to get information about routes between elements using Viewer API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to create web application using `autodesk` forge API, and want to get output of information about routes between elements. In brief, the application  outputs the shortest path between two elements when they are selected.

I tried it using `getIsolated()` and `isolate()` but I can't understand what the "isolated" state is, so I can't.

please  teach  me the how to solve this challenge.

I'm sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Isolation is a way to highlight certain objects in the scene by making other objects "ghosted" (semitransparent) or hidden completely. If you want to actually *select* objects, use the `.select()` and `.getSelection()` methods.

Forge Viewer does not provide any path planning unfortunately. It can give you the bounding boxes of all objects in the scene (here's an [example](https://petrbroz.github.io/forge-viewer-utils/master/Utilities.html#getFragmentBounds-examples)) but you would have to find the path among them yourself.